# Don't take into account edit with only nonsignificant characters

Tags: feature-request

On one of my questions, I got an [edit of 90 white spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/12314967/revisions).

I think that our engine should reject that automatically.

Comment: With the way markdown works, a small number of spaces can make a big difference to how a question appears.

Comment: @TZHX so please enlight me about this edit: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/12314967/revisions

Comment: I would guess they thought they were editing [their answer](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/12315035/revisions), and undid it within the grace period.

Comment: The edit was made by a user with over 2k rep, so there's not much stopping them. Feel free to roll back if it bothers you. Hilariously, they didn't correct the spelling mistake in "dupplicate".

Comment: that's not a big deal for me, I just thought that forbidding whitespace only edit could be a legitimate request

Comment: well I have not much support. so let's greet full white spaces edits.

Comment: Weird edit, indeed... a couple of obvious things unfixed... Did you try to ask why to the `@editor`?

Comment: how to communicate personnally ?

Answer (score 2):

Well, the editor didn't actually add 90 whitespaces.

What he did was editing it normally, and then just after submitting but before the grace-period ended, he though better of it and undid his changes as best he could (he was wrong by one newline).

If he had succeeded, he would have removed one newline less, which would have changed the summary to

> [Edit removed during grace period]

I have a feature-request on MSE to allow rollbacks to have that result.
Avoiding the manual fiddling would not have resulted in a useless insignificant-space difference:

[Let's be smarter when rolling back in the grace-period](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263752/lets-be-smarter-when-rolling-back-in-the-grace-period)